# Como utilizar CASE WHEN em uma instrução IN?

Tags: sql-server, select, case

Em uma `query` estou a reunir dados sobre representantes, clientes e vendedores.

Alguns representantes possuem vendedores, que por sua vez possuem clientes. Esses casos são excepcionais, pois os clientes são ligados diretamente aos seus representantes.

Ao tentar utilizar uma `subquery` com `case`:

```
SELECT
vw.regional,
vw.cod_gerente,
vw.nome_gerente,
vw.cod_representante,
vw.nome_representante,
vw.cod_vendedor,
vw.nome_vendedor,
SUM(t.valor_original) AS total_valor_original
FROM vw_regional_gerente_representante_vendedor vw
INNER JOIN vwTitulosPagos t ON t.cod_representante = vw.cod_representante
WHERE 1 = 1
AND t.cod_cliente IN (
    CASE WHEN vw.cod_representante IN (59,77,147) THEN
        (SELECT DISTINCT cod_cliente FROM vendedores_x_clientes WHERE cod_vendedor = vw.cod_vendedor) 
    ELSE 
        t.cod_cliente 
    END
)
AND t.saldo = 0
AND t.data_movto BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/08/2016',103) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '31/08/2016',103)
GROUP BY
vw.regional,
vw.cod_gerente,
vw.nome_gerente,
vw.cod_representante,
vw.nome_representante,
vw.cod_vendedor,
vw.nome_vendedor
ORDER BY vw.regional, vw.nome_gerente, vw.nome_representante, vw.nome_vendedor
```

Ocorre o seguinte erro:

> SQL Error [512] [S0001]: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is
>   not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when
>   the subquery is used as an expression.
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Subquery returned
>   more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =,
>   !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

De fato a subquery retornará mais de um resultado, porém é o esperado para utilizar dentro da cláusula `IN`, porém isto somente ocorre dentro do `case`.

Estou tentando desta maneira e procurando outras soluções que não seja utilizando `UNION`.

Comment: Você poderia posta o seu select inteiro?

Comment: Editado, @GOKUSSJ4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não vai consegui dessa forma porque o select retorna os elementos do select UM a UM e não uma lista de int, o que você pode fazer é contorna sua cláusula AND com duas condições verificando o `vw.cod_representante IN` e sua condição `t.cod_cliente IN` e um `OR` negando a condição anterior `t.cod_cliente  = t.cod_cliente` e `and vw.cod_representante NOT IN`

Assim;

```
AND (  ((t.cod_cliente IN 
        (SELECT DISTINCT cod_cliente 
            FROM vendedores_x_clientes 
            WHERE cod_vendedor = vw.cod_vendedor) 
        and vw.cod_representante IN (59,77,147))
       )
or     ((t.cod_cliente  = t.cod_cliente) 
        and vw.cod_representante NOT IN (59,77,147))
    )
```